# Create file in memory using python and assign a name to file (universal naming convention)?

Tags: python, unc, in-memory, bytesio

Using a library such as Python's `io`, I can create a file e.g. csv format, in memory. However, I cannot get a UNC (Universal Naming Convention) referencing this file. How would I be able to assign such a name to an in-memory file created by Python?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you expecting the UNC name to enable you to access a "memory file" from outside the process?

Comment: Are you trying to write a file to disk and then read what it's file directory is?

Comment: @dirck7 I am only expecting it to let me access the file. Whether access is outside the process or not does not concern me.

Comment: @rangeseeker that is exactly what I want to AVOID doing. I want to write in memory, not in disk.

Answer (score 0):

A "file" created in memory using the `io` module is not a "file" as far as the OS is concerned.  You can't open it by name or access it from outside the process.  This file only exists as a variable in the program.

You can get the string contents directly, as in the example @ https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO

```
import io

output = io.StringIO()
output.write('First line.\n')
print('Second line.', file=output)
contents = output.getvalue()
```

or you can rewind the file and read it back:

```
output.seek(0)
contents = output.read()
```